# ORDER BY translated fields

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `posts` and `post_translations`. A post can be translated into many languages, and its translations are stored in the `post_translations` table. Not all posts are available in all languages.

### `posts`:

```
+----+------+
| id | hits |
+----+------+
|  1 |   12 |
+----+------+
|  2 |   34 |
+-----------+
```

### `post_translations`:

```
+----+---------+--------+---------------+------+
| id | post_id | locale | title         | body |
+----+---------+--------+---------------+------+
|  1 |       1 |     en | Hello, world! | Hey. |
+----+---------+------------------------+------+
|  2 |       1 |     es | ¡Hola, mundo! | Olé. |
+----+---------+--------+---------------+------+
|  3 |       2 |     en |  How are you? | Meh. |
+----+---------+--------+---------------+------+
```

I'd like to `SELECT` all `posts`, ordered by Spanish `title`—but, since not all posts are available in Spanish, I'd also like to fall back to English `title` if necessary. That is, `ORDER BY title_with_fallbacks` where `title_with_fallbacks = [spanish title] || [english title]`.

I suppose I could use a dependent subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY (SELECT name FROM post_translations
                              WHERE post_id = posts.id
                              ORDER BY FIELD(locale, 'es', 'en')
                              LIMIT 1)
```

But that could get nasty fast if there are thousands of results. Any clever ideas of how to get the same result by joining the two tables or something along those lines?

(For reference, I'm using the Rails plugin [globalize3](http://rubygems.org/gems/globalize3), but I haven't been able to find any built-in mechanism to get this job done.)

Comment: If I get desperate, I guess I could create a placeholder `es` translation that's just a copy of `en`, and then just work with the one-to-one posts-to-`es`-translations relationships… but if this can be accomplished *without* changing a bunch of app logic, that'd be nice.

Comment: Meh, those results don't really illustrate it well, especially because there are only two posts. I might post a more legit example if necessary…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query accomplishes the conditional ordering with two `left joins`... One to the Spanish translation, and another to the English translation...

The `ORDER BY` then uses the `IFNULL` function to order by the Spanish title, and if the Spanish title is `NULL`, order by the English title instead.

```
SELECT p.id, p.hits, IFNULL(es_pt.title, en_pt.title) AS locale_title
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN post_translations es_pt
    ON p.id = pt.post_id AND es_pt.locale = 'es'
LEFT JOIN post_translations en_pt
    ON p.ID = pt.post_id AND en_pt.locale = 'en'
ORDER BY IFNULL(es_pt.title, en_pt.title)
```

Comment: Ooh, clever! I'll go play with this for a minute…

Comment: Awesome, results look good :D (And today I learned the `IFNULL` function—doubt I would've found that on my own.) Thanks! This one was gonna have me stumped for a while :P

Comment: @Matchu I probably should have used `COALESCE` instead of `IFNULL`... since `COALESCE` is ANSI standard...

Comment: Hmm: this query ends up performing about the same as the dependent subquery solution. I guess the `COALESCE` is forcing it into the same filesort as the subquery did :/ I'll keep this answer marked as accepted for now, but, if someone comes along and outperforms it, they'll get the checkmark.